# What creates a function in a function?

Tags: javascript

Why is the result of the following code 1 and not 10? Why doesn't the function bar() change the value, even though there is a return statement.

```
var foo = 1;
function bar() {
  foo = 10;
  return;

  function foo() {}
}

bar();
alert(foo);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `function` definitions are hoisted to the top of their scope, so the foo assignment inside `bar()` is actually referring to the local function that has an empty body.

You can read more about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting)

Answer (score 3):

This is because while compiling the `foo` function declaration inside `bar` moves on the top of the `bar`. Like this

```
var foo = 1;
function bar() {
  function foo() {}
  foo = 10;
  return;
}

bar();
alert(foo);
```

Read about [hoisting in JS](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp).
And [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) in the "var hoisting" section